# Scheduled Task error - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

```
Application: LMS2RecurringAssignmentApp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 6.0.21.52210
.NET Version: 6.0.0
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

This error was solved in our local environment by setting the appsettings.json "Copy to output directory" property to "copy if newer" but we are now getting it when the console application runs on the server as a scheduled task.

Comment: If possible for you then could you please try to share the sample code for your connection string from `appsettings.json` file? It could be possible that the code contains some issue or error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the folder structure was different when running locally in Visual Studio vs when built/published on the server.

The solution was to call `SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)` on the `ConfigurationBuilder` to get the correct path in both situations.

```
    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                (hostContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);
                })
            .ConfigureServices(
                (hostContext, services) =>
                {

                }
            );
    }
```